# linkedin login need linkedin app in device ios

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

For login with LinkedIn my app it displays that "You need to download the LinkedIn App in order to connect with linked" because i don't have app LinkedIn app installed in my device.

But my question is, is there any way without installing LinkedIn in device login with LinkedIn from my app?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: yes, you can use the rest API.

Comment: this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/linkedin-sign-in/) using API to login LinkedIn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES.
I have using the following library for LinkedIn login : https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI.
(This library uses the REST API of LinkedIn for login).

If you are using the official LinkedIn SDK, then you need to have the LinkedIn app installed in device for Sign In.